# Strange VIH and VIL specification of MIC4451

Tags: voltage, microchip

In [MIC4451's datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4451.pdf), it shows:

[image]

The \$V_{IH}\$ min. is 2.4V, then where the smaller typical value 1.3V come from? The same is \$V_{IL}\$, why it has a typical value larger than the max. value?

Comment: Janka nailed it... This is how these are almost always specified. It becomes 2nd nature over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a TTL compatible **input**.

- 2.4V and above is guaranteed to be understood as logic 1, but typical 1.3V or above is sufficient.
- 0.8V and below is guaranteed to be understood as logic 0, but typical 1.1V or below is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

This is, in my opinion, a confusing usage of the terms max and min. What they're saying is that the *minimum* voltage you should apply to an input that you want to drive high is 2.4V, but a typical device will read anything down to 1.3V as high--it's just not guaranteed.

Likewise, the *maximum* voltage you should apply when driving a signal low is 0.8V, but typical devices will interpret up to 1.1V as low.

It does feel backwards to me, too; you're not alone in that.

Comment: Are they promising 0.2 volts of hysteresis?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf No, I don't think there's any hysteresis in this. The region between 1.1 and 1.3 volts I would assume has undefined behavior. The device is fundamentally a high-current, fast logic buffer, so I'm guessing it would have a region where it outputs something between its output high and output low voltages, and they're just saying that this region is typically no more than 0.2 volts wide. This is, however, all a guess. Undocumented behavior shouldn't be used in an actual design, of course!

Comment: I would describe 2.4 as a *max*, since it's the *highest* value Vih could take on an acceptable part — but the concept of maximum minimums tends to confuse people, who would read the datasheet and decide that they shouldn't apply a voltage above 2.4V. Sometimes there's no winning.

Comment: @hobbs Even in the most precise technical fields, language is sometimes hard.